# why authorization code is necessary in authorization-grant-type

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am new to OAuth and was wondering why authorization code is required?

Why authorization does not send access token or refresh token in callback response.

why not directly access token?

Comment: Authorization code grant type provides an extra step when compared to the implicit grant type. 
Through this extra step it provides some additional security benefits it passes the access token directly to the client application without exposing to the user of the application or any other third party. Also it allows to authenticate the client since in the first call it sends a request to the authorize endpoint to get the code and then in the next step it makes a call to the token endpoint with Authorization header to get the access token.

Answer (score 3):

The Authorization Code grant uses the short-lived one-time `code` so that it can be exchanged for the real token (which is longer-lived and multiple-use) in a backchannel call that is more secure and can leverage credentials to authenticate the Client towards the Authorization Server.

The Implicit grant type returns the access token directly in the authorization response. It is considered to be more insecure because it is easier to attack (using crafted redirects etc.) and because there's no way to keep a client credentials secret.

Comment: How backchannel call is more secure? If I am calling both using https from same web server

Comment: one is a redirect, susceptible to all kinds of attacks, the other is a direct https call

Comment: I have found this nice article on this topic, but not sure how the redirection is susceptible to attacks. can someone explain it here with an example? https://medium.com/@vidura.prasangana16/what-is-oauth-2-0-476aabded278